# Elder Scrolls Lore: Oghma Infinium

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

I got curious about the Oghma Infinium, so I looked around in some forums then I found something about a text writen in Portuguese, in the Oghma. It was about the Dwemer, icebergs, the Septimus-guy... Sadly, I must pay to see the full content. I am Portuguese, if someone would get me the text I could translate it.

Comment: If someone is trying to sell you TES content, they're most likely in violation of copyright laws. I don't think I've ever acquired that book in one of the games, but if there's no text to be shown, there's no official one.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something related to it at the library. http://www.imperial-library.info/search/node/Oghma%20%20type%3Abook

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the text was somehow "hidden" in the book. I found some more things, in the second page, the things/draws/painting look like the Imperial City

Answer (score 6):

I have found [this resource](https://www.reddit.com/r/teslore/comments/16unq3/second_page_of_the_oghma_infinium_translated/) covering the translation of the Oghma Infinium. It's only the second page, but it says:

> O de historia de Nirn foi vasto e profundo ir de Winterhold magia mente fala ele. Comandos do Dwemer esperando encontrar a um erro, mais conhecimento mais segredo. Ele ora durante as poucas decadas passadas e te nas suas investigaes le consequentemente de afec mais o discernimento consente senhor Daedric no mundo assassinato. Aqui umas camas da Skyrim Septimus e ice doenca curas a. Dwemer aqui veste o eu a na dano sal case on um Dunsmir lockbox congelado no gelo.

I have found an additional resource [here](http://www.imperial-library.info/content/oghma-infinium-research) which is mostly the first page, but it is mostly speculation and not everything it set in stone yet:

> No centro deste iceberg entretanto um grande dwarv lockbox septim esculpiu uma caverna no icberg para que em lado do lockbox essencialmente o iceberg foi criado em volta do lockbox por alguma pessoa desconhecida dentro da pouca centena ltmia de anos esta pessoa enco trou o oghma infinium reconheceu o como um in mento da maldade e sel longe na banda lockbox iceberg para que o ede no precisa de ser um grande espaço mas deve haver um lugar ???

<sup>Note that I have removed casing and section seperation. There was no punctuation, so that's a problem.</sup>

---

For sake of completeness, I've tried to compile most of the Oghma Infinium lore here. This does not include pieces from the translation because that's not considered a solid source yet. This is just some random information into the background of the book that you may find interesting.

It comes from a couple sources, namely the [Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Oghma_Infinium_%28Skyrim%29) and [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Oghma_Infinium). I have also included some of my own interpretations of the lore and ideas within -- take this with a grain of salt.

> The Oghma Infinium is a divine artifact created by the god Xarxes using knowledge granted to him by the Daedric Prince Hermaeus Mora. Reading the book is said to give access to knowledge beyond the belief of man.
>
> The actual book was found by the Ayleids in the First Era. The Ayleids attempted to understand this book by using it and another book, the Book of the Frozen Legion. However, their city was destroyed (whether coincidentally, by the books, or by the gods is unclear).
>
> In 2E 582, the Ayleids and the Bosmer were one and the same. They guarded this book with their lives until the Imperials came in search of the Oghma Infinium. The Imperial in charge, Gracchus, eventually found the two books and tried to extract information on how to defeat the Aldmeri Dominion. However, Hermaeus Mora decided that he was not worthy to use such a powerful artifact, and he killed Gracchus. After his death, the Oghma Infinium returned back to Apocrypha.
>
> Later (year unknown, likely 2E or early 3E), Hermaeus Mora tempted a Blades agent to kill a lord in exchange for the use of the book.
>
> In 3E 433, Hermaeus Mora again put the book up as a reward to his Champion, this time being the Hero of Kvatch (the protagonist in TES IV). Once the Hero of Kvatch finished his duties, he was granted the Oghma Infinium.
>
> Some time likely in the Fourth Era, the Oghma Infinium was locked in an ancient Dwemer lockbox north of Skyrim. Displeased with this, Hermaeus Mora manipulated one of his agents, Septimus Signus, into finding a way to open the Lockbox to find the "heart of a god" contained within. In 4E 201, the Last Dragonborn comes to Septimus Signus, where he/she is redirected to Blackreach to extract information on the lockbox from an Elder Scroll.
>
> After succeeding to extract this information, Septimus translates the information (stored on a Dwemer Lexicon) and finds that the lockbox can only be opened with Dwemer blood. As a result, the Last Dragonborn was tasked with getting the blood from the different Mer races in order to allow Septimus to "trick" the lockbox.
>
> Upon receiving his blood samples, Septimus injects himself with the proper mixture and succeeds in opening the lockbox. Inside, he finds the Oghma Infinium still in its pristine condition. However, with Septimus' use fulfilled, Hermaeus Mora kills Septimus and awards the Oghma Infinium to the Last Dragonborn, instructing him/her to act as his Champion.
>
> It is unknown if the Last Dragonborn has actually read the book, or where it currently is today. Some suspect that the book is stored in a chest contained within Breezehome of Whiterun.

Comment: My hands hurt after typing all of this.